# link self created android Library with other project

Tags: android, android-library

I created a project "`ScreenSaver`" and a module inside it named "`screensaver`" 
Path for the project is "`C:\Users\sadip_000\StudioProjects\mp\`"
and module is "`C:\Users\sadip_000\StudioProjects\mp\ScreenSaver\`"
But the gradle says project with path not found
what might be the issue?

settings.gradle in the prj I want to use the library is:

```
include ':app'
include ':screensaver'
project(':screenSaver').projectDir=new File('C:\\Users\\sadip_000\\StudioProjects\\WOD\\ScreenSaver\\screensaver')
```

Comment: Please show your Gradle file

Comment: I've added the settings.gradle file